# How to share a private spreadsheet on a public site using Awesome Table gadget

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-gadget

I would like to run the google awesome table gadget for a public site by accessing a private sheet url. This is to protect the data, otherwise the sheet url is visible to the public and they can copy the whole sheet. I want users to get the information only through the site.

How can I accomplish this. Is there a way to run the gadget like app script where it run as myself.

Do I need to modify the gadget xml to access my private sheet like app script?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a proxy script between your private sheet and the public site. This will not hide the sheet URL, but avoids the need to share the sheet itself.

In the documentation for Awesome Tables, see "[Use row-level permissions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G9JiOOFT5VKYGITvrLdlv0pBnJM0rXdrruSd91zAcCM/edit#heading=h.mwwewii4ya94)", which describes how to set up a proxy script. Instead of controlling display of specific rows, however, this simple proxy will serve your entire table, while hiding the underlying spreadsheet from the public.

1. Set up your Awesome Table spreadsheet & gadget normally. There is no special configuration of your data required.
2. Deploy the Simple Proxy script as a web app.

   - Copy the script below into a new script in your account.
   - Run it once to authorize it.
   - Deploy it as a web app, "Execute as me", Access to "anyone, including anonymous".
   - Copy the public URL of the app.
3. On the "Advanced parameters" tab of the Awesome Table gadget, paste the public URL of your Simple Proxy into the "Apps Script Proxy URL" field.

#### Simple Proxy.gs

This script was adapted from Romain's original, removing the Domain-only features that provided user-level data filtering.

```
// Simple proxy for AwesomeTables
// Adapted from https://script.google.com/d/1UfKnjB6jcemv5-BRP-ckaI5UCoEQI2KuvFdjNzmLpyadelNLCwpvaFsO/edit
function doGet(e) {
  var ssUrl =  e.parameter.url;
  var sheetName = e.parameter.sheet;
  var a1Notation = e.parameter.range;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssUrl).getSheetByName(sheetName); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(a1Notation); 
  var data = range.getValues();
  var dt = {cols:[], rows:[]};
  for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    dt.cols.push({id:i, label:data[0][i] + ' ' + data[1][i], type: 'string', isNumber:true, isDate:true});
  }
  for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
      var row = [];
      for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        if(isNaN(data[i][j])) dt.cols[j].isNumber = false;
        if(data[i][j] instanceof Date == false) dt.cols[j].isDate = false;
        else if(data[i][j].getFullYear() == 1899) {
          dt.cols[j].isDate = false;
          data[i][j] = data[i][j].getHours()+':'+(data[i][j].getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+data[i][j].getMinutes();
        }
        else data[i][j] = "Date("+data[i][j].getTime()+")";
        row.push({v:data[i][j]});
      }
      dt.rows.push({c:row});
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
    if(dt.cols[i].isDate) dt.cols[i].type = 'datetime';
    else if(dt.cols[i].isNumber) dt.cols[i].type = 'number';
  }
  var output = e.parameters.callback + '(' + JSON.stringify({
    dataTable: dt
  }) + ')';
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

#### Caveats

- A user will be able to view the URL of your spreadsheet in the HTML source for the page hosting Awesome Tables. If you have enabled sharing, the spreadsheet could be wide open to them.
- A single Simple Proxy can serve ALL spreadsheets that your account has access to. This is both a feature and a risk that you should be aware of.

Comment: Hi Mogsdad,Thank you for your help. I tried this and is working.

Comment: Hi Mogsdad,Thank you for your help. I tried this and is working. However I find the page loading time has increased considerable more (earlier 3s, now 10s). This seems to be due to traversing through data in the script. In order to speed up, Can we do these actions in advance and store the table/json into a file and read it during appscript invocation. I know that in that case the sheet url etc will be hardcoded. But still Ok to speed up. Don't know what is the best way to save the pre-constructed table and retrieve. if you can guide on that will be very helpful. Thanks  Hari

Comment: The basic idea is sound. Try it, and if you get stuck come back and ask more specific questions.

Comment: I have saved the json string to a file and the speed is back. However the card view is not working. It always show table view. This is true for the original code and nothing to do with file saving. What can be the reason for it? Thank you.  Hari

Comment: @user3887453 - you should ask that as a separate question, or as a support question for the Awesome Table author.